# java.io.FileNotFoundException when uploading file with p:fileupload primefaces

Tags: file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces

I have sometimes this error when I upload files using p:fileupload component :

```
    3 avr. 2013 12:02:10 com.sun.faces.renderkit.ClientSideStateHelper doGetState
GRAVE: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\upload_62661b9d_13dcf1c54c0__8000_00000270.tmp (Le fichier spécifié est introuvable)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\upload_62661b9d_13dcf1c54c0__8000_00000270.tmp (Le fichier spécifié est introuvable)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.readObject(DiskFileItem.java:719)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

if I upload only one file it works fine, but when I try to upload more I have this problem

here is my code :

```
    <h:form  prependId="false" enctype="multipart/form-data">


                <p:fileUpload   mode="advanced" widgetVar="monupload"   auto="true"
                    style="display:none;" id="ajouterUpload" styleClass="monfileupload"
                     fileUploadListener="#{articlesMB.handleFileUpload}"  />
                <p:commandLink id="mylink" onclick="uploaderAjouter();">
                    <h:graphicImage id="Ajouterimage"
                        value="http://localhost:8080/images/without.png" height="48"
                        width="48"  />
                </p:commandLink>

            </h:form>
```

I tested also to set this below to web.xml but the same error but with the new path :(

```
     <init-param>
    <param-name>uploadDirectory</param-name>
    <param-value>/Users/primefaces/temp</param-value>
  </init-param>
```

do you have any idea

I think the problem is from the OS no?

thank you

Comment: I used this path "D:/tmp/". Maybe try put C: too. I also have this filter in web file: org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter

Comment: I use this filter too, but it doesn't fix the problem

Comment: can you explain me more, how the system handle this tmp file and ...

Comment: try remove enctype="multipart/form-data". I have simple form <h:form id="addRecordForm">

Answer (score 0):

You need multiple="true" for [uploading multiple files](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadMultiple.jsf).

```
<p:fileUpload multiple="true" ...>
```

Comment: Did you added commons-fileupload, commons-io jars into your classpath? Also remove uploadDirectory params, you do not need it for temp files

Comment: can be uploadDirectory. Works for me with it.